# Extract data from the application

Tags: web-scraping, websocket, extract, spring-websocket

I want to find the information or addresses that the mobile or desktop application communicates with,
but I can't.

I want to find out somehow how the user name search process is done inside it.
What method is passed, to which URL address .

It can be explained that this application that I want to extract has only desktop and mobile versions. There is no web version.

Until this moment, I realized that information is transferred with WebSocket.

Do you know a program that extracts addresses and methods?

The applications that I have tested so far. I lost.

1. URL Extractor (Desktop)
2. HTTP.Debugger.9.12 (Destop)
3. Packet Capture (Mobile)

Neither gave me a line that worked.